# How do I set the individual upload file names?

Tags: laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5.3 app that has a form which users can upload multiple files using multiple *file* fields. The form work in that the files can be uploaded and moed to the destinationPath as I expect but I can't seem to change each of the files 'filename' values.  It keeps saving the filename value as the php**.tmp.

Here is the foreach in my controller;

```
        $files = $request->files;

    foreach($files as $file){
        $destinationPath = 'images/forms'; // upload path
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName(); // get image name
        $file->move($destinationPath, $filename); // uploading file to given path
        $file->filename = $filename;
    }
```

If I `dd($filename)` and `dd($file->filename)` within the foreach I do get the value (original name) I am looking for but if I `dd($files)` outside that foreach, the filename is set as the temp php value.

What am I missing?  Thanks.

**EDIT**

The file object looks like this;

-test: false

-originalName: "sample_header_1280.png"

-mimeType: "image/png"

-size: 51038

-error: 0

path: "C:\xampp\tmp"

filename: "php7240.tmp"

basename: "php7240.tmp"

pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\php7240.tmp"

extension: "tmp"

realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\php7240.tmp"

I am trying to save the originalName to the db but it seems to default to saving the filename.

Comment: why are you using the last line inside the foreach?

Comment: I am trying to set the file filename value.  See my edit for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out using a foreach for Input::file is not he approach here.  If uploading multiple files from the same field - then you'd use a foreach to loop, move and save.

To upload files from multiple *file* inputs on the same form all you need to do is treat each input individually - as you might with any other form.

In my example I did this in my controller;

```
    $data['image1'] = Input::file('image1')->getClientOriginalName();
    Input::file('image1')->move($destinationPath, $data['image1']);

    $data['image2'] = Input::file('image2')->getClientOriginalName();
    Input::file('image2')->move($destinationPath, $data['image2']);
```

Not sure this is the best approach (there's always another way) but it worked for me.